# default ResourceBase in ServletContextHandler in jetty

Tags: eclipse, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm using ServletContextHandler.

Here is the example:

```
    Server server = new Server();


    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setResourceBase("C:\Demo");
    context.setContextPath("/");
    server.setHandler(context);
    server.start();
```

So, As far as my understanding, please correct me if I'm wrong, that files available under "C:\Demo" can be accessed using "localhost:8081/" as resourcebase is set to this location and context path is defined as "/".

So What if we don't set the resource base then to which directory "localhost:8081/" will point?

Answer (score 0):

It wont point to anything.

And you'll also have a tough time configuring things that need a valid [`javax.servlet.ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)

Any servlet or library that needs configuration from the following `ServletContext` methods would fail without a Base Resource defined.

```java
String      ServletContext.getRealPath(String path)
URL         ServletContext.getResource(String path)
InputStream ServletContext.getResourceAsStream(String path)
Set<String> ServletContext.getResources(String path)
```